# C# how do i create a DateTime Variable that has the current date, but a different time?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to compute the difference between two dates(time). the current date(time) and a DateTime variable that has the current date but a different time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a viable question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not how it works here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *What* different time? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The variable type DateTime gives off two things. the Date and the Time. you can get those two separately. The question is how do I create a DateTime value that has the current Date But it has a different time for instance:

DateTime X = DateTime.Now; //This gives the current date + the current time. 

I want to create a DateTime variable that can hold the current Date but holds a different time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timespan is what you need.

```
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            TimeSpan time2 = new TimeSpan(15, 23, 30); //(15h:23m:00s)
            TimeSpan dif = time2 - now;
```

Comment: I think you should not give answer until correct question is asked

Comment: The question is wrongly expressed , but i think i understood what he wants to do.

Comment: He must search on google first. We are not here to do homework. Else people will downgrade your answer. Same happened with me before :p

Comment: Well you might have a point on that.